# How to get combobox to create a new object in response to text type in by the user?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have items stored in the ItemSource property of a combobox, however, when the user types in a name that does not exist in the list I need it to create a new object and use that as the SelectedObject. I am pretty new to WPF and used to WindowsForms, so I might just be going about doing this the totally wrong way, any input is appreciated.

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ComboExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cboName"  IsEditable="True" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"></ComboBox>
    <DockPanel>
        <Label>Selected Value</Label>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBox>
    </DockPanel>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Click Me</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

and code behind (which displays "value is null" if you type a new value in

```
    class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass(string name) {this.Name = name;}

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cboName.ItemsSource = new SomeClass[] { new SomeClass("A"), new SomeClass("B") };
        cboName.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
        cboName.SelectedItem = cboName.ItemsSource.OfType<SomeClass>().FirstOrDefault();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SomeClass value = cboName.SelectedValue as SomeClass;
        if (value == null)
            MessageBox.Show("No item is selected.");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("An item is selected.");
    }

    SomeClass empty = new SomeClass("");
    private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = cboName.SelectedItem as SomeClass;
        if (DataContext == null)
            cboName.SelectedValue = DataContext = empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here one way to do it:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cboName" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxItems}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding ComboBoxItems[0],Mode=OneTime}"  IsEditable="True"/>
    <DockPanel>
        <Label>Selected Value</Label>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Name,ElementName=cboName}"></TextBox>
    </DockPanel>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Click Me</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

and the code behind :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private ObservableCollection<SomeClass> _comboBoxItems;
    public ObservableCollection<SomeClass> ComboBoxItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _comboBoxItems;
        }

        set
        {
            _comboBoxItems = value;
        }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        ComboBoxItems = new ObservableCollection<SomeClass>()
        {
            new SomeClass("First Name"),
            new SomeClass("Second Name"),
            new SomeClass("Third Name")
        };

    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ComboBoxItems.Any(x => x.Name == cboName.Text))
        {
            ComboBoxItems.Add(new SomeClass(cboName.Text));
        }
    }
}
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass(string name) { this.Name = name; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

To better manage your objects you may consider

- defining a new property For the Selected `ComboBox` Item (Of Type `SomeClass`), and bind it to the `ComboBox` `SelectedItem`,
- Use `ObservableCollection` instead of just list and Implement the `INotifyPropertyChanges` `Interface`.